# Word VBA Find and Replace all occurences step by step

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing a word macro which should find all occurences of a string in my document (example: "see picture 1") and then replace the number with a new number which gets increased  with every found occurence. Accordingly, the second occurence should be changed to "see picture 2", the third one to "see picture 3" and so on.

I have a problem with my code, because it changes the first found occurence every iteration of the loop and doesnt move on to the second one. So after 10 iterations of the loop, the first occurence is "see picture 10" and all the other ones are still "see picture 1". This is the code I use:

```
     With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
        .Text = "see picture [0-9]@"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        
        Do While .Execute(ReplaceWith:="(siehe Foto" + str(i), Replace:=wdReplaceOne)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
            
    End With
```

How can I get the macro to go through every occurence of the string one by one and replace the (random) number with an increasing number?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Change `.Wrap = wdFindStop` to `.Wrap = wdFindContinue`.

Comment: You might be better off if instead of replacing with a hard coded string, replace the 1 with a seq field such that if a picture subsequently gets inserted, the numbering will automatically update.

Comment: @freeflow Thank you, that did the trick!